# Factory reset Android using ADB

Tags: adb, factory-reset

I am trying to factory data reset my Oppo Neo 7 (Android 5.1) using ADB shell. Any way I can try and link to ADB shell?

Comment: Similar Question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb

Comment: For my ROM, nothing here worked. But I found this: `wipedata`.

Answer (score 16):

You need:

- [Minimal ADB & Fastboot](https://androidmtk.com/download-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-tool) which contains ADB executable then unzip the file
- [ADB drivers](https://gsmusbdriver.com/oppo-neo-7) and install them
- A computer

Steps:

1. Open the folder where Minimal ADB & Fastboot is, launch it.
2. Now on your phone, enable USB Debugging, then connect to the computer.
3. On the terminal window, type `adb devices` [press enter].
   You should see something like: `xxxxxxxxx device detected`
4. Type `adb shell`  [press enter]
5. Type `recovery --wipe_data` [press enter], or if it doesn't work, type `wipe data`[press enter]
6. Your phone should restart and begin the restoration process.

**Alternate Option**

You can also simply boot into the recovery then perform the reset manually. Type the following command on your terminal:

```
adb reboot recovery
```

Comment: Worked for me! I had a Xiaomi Redme 7A, Android 9.0, which I had corrupted so badly I couldn't do a factory reset through Settings. So I went through your options. First `adb shell` and then `recovery wipe_data`, and got "... recovery: not found". Ditto for `wipe data`. Then I tried `adb reboot recovery` and the device responded (Joy!!!), and gave me a short sequence of confirmation dialogs, driven from the Volume Up/Down and power keys, and then did with the reset. The device was NOT in fastboot mode. It was just attached to the USB, with normal developer options enabled.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127473/discussion-on-answer-by-esqmo-how-to-factory-reset-android-using-adb).

Comment: Not sure why this answer has so many upvotes but it is wrong at half. `adb shell` [has no command](https://technastic.com/adb-shell-commands-list/) `recovery`. Only small last part `You can also simply boot into the recovery` is correct (is it outdated?)

Answer (score 9):

For devices that support Fastboot mode, you can try the following commands:

1. Enter fastboot mode: `adb reboot bootloader`
2. Check whether the mobile phone is also in fastboot mode: `fastboot devices`
3. Delete the data: `fastboot erase userdata`
4. Delete cache: `fastboot erase cache`

Comment: What if the device doesn't support Fastboot commands?

Comment: good point. Then your solution will need to be used. Many devices support fastboot commands, so I think this is a good option in most cases.

Comment: @esQmo_ Which devices?

Comment: source 404; if we delete data, cache will also delete?

Comment: @SmartManoj Samsung devices don't support fastboot commands. Deleting data also deletes cache