# How to wipe data on a bootloader-locked, broken screen, Nexus 6P

Tags: adb, factory-reset, fastboot, broken-screen, nexus-6p

I want to sell my Nexus 6P for parts, but I want to wipe it first. The screen of my Nexus 6P broke (internally, the touchscreen MIGHT be fine, idk). The phone is full-disk encrypted with a PIN and the bootloader is locked (no root). I can't fully boot the phone since it will be stuck on the FDE pin entry.

As we know the Nexus 6P does not have [external monitor support](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/46yjfn/external_display_support/) - so this is not an option. I do have ADB and Fastboot access, but commands like

```
fastboot erase userdata
```

are blocked, since the bootloader is locked. Also various `adb shell` commands did not work.

### What I tried:

#### ADB Shell: Recovery --wipe_data

```
adb shell
recovery --wipe_data
/system/bin/sh: recovery: not found
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685721/how-can-i-do-factory-reset-using-adb-in-android)

#### ADB Shell: Wipe Data

```
adb shell
wipe data
/system/bin/sh: wipe: not found
```

[source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175885/how-to-factory-reset-android-using-adb)

#### Fastboot: Wipe

```
adb devices       # Check the phone is running
adb reboot bootloader
# Wait a few seconds
fastboot devices  # Check the phone is in bootloader
fastboot -w       # Wipe user data
Erasing 'userdata'   FAILED (remote: device is locked. Cannot erase)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357553/774398)

#### Fastboot: Erase

```
adb devices       # Check the phone is running
adb reboot bootloader
# Wait a few seconds
fastboot devices  # Check the phone is in bootloader
fastboot erase userdata
Erasing 'userdata'   FAILED (remote: device is locked. Cannot erase)
```

[source](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175887/48335)

So the question is, what are my options to wipe my phone?

Comment: You could simply do an `fastboot oem unlock` reboot and then relock the bootloader. Unlocking erases all the user data.

Comment: I think I would need to start the oem unlock in developers settings in the OS, no?

Comment: Right I forgot that, on current devices AFAIR you have to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work. The base of the solution was to use [adb screen casting](https://www.vysor.io). I was lucky, the apk was installed and I could remote control the device and made a OS factory reset.