# How to wipe and reinstall an encrypted device with 7.1.2 if TWRP won't boot anymore?

Tags: factory-reset, twrp, encryption, 7.1-nougat

I installed an [unofficial build](https://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/development/rom-aicp-nougat-12-0-unofficial-t3478872) of Resurrection Remix 7.1.2 on Meizu Pro 5 (M86) with TWRP 3.0.2. Out of curiosity I then enabled encryption with the thought that even if I don't like it and cannot reverse, I should be able to rollback the previous system backup via TWRP. There is no data to care about, but still I want to be able to install on the phone whatever I want.

I was wrong. TWRP won't boot anymore. Its boot screen appears but just flashes every 5 seconds or so.

I then tried a few things:

- Factory reset from the Settings. I can reach the "Erase Everything" button but it does nothing;
- [Factory reset from ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175885/how-to-factory-reset-android-using-adb):

  - `recovery --wipe_data` says `/system/bin/sh: recovery: not found`
  - `wipe data` says `/system/bin/sh: wipe: not found`
  - After `adb reboot bootloader` I have no luck running `fastboot devices`: it outputs nothing
- Attempting to flash a newer version of TWRP from TWRP App (image for Meizu Note 6; there is none for my device) but it complains that the device is not rooted (the developer settings only allow root via ADB).

So is there a way to just wipe the device and re-install something on it?

Comment: `recovery --wipe_data` is supposed to be run when you are in recovery mode. `wipe data` is not a valid command at all. You can write `--wipe_data` to `/cache/recovery/command` file and then reboot to recovery mode using `adb reboot recovery` command. If recovery mode isn't booting, boot into bootloader mode and boot recovery from there.