# Reset PIN from adb shell

Tags: adb, locked-out

I have forgotten the PIN of a device but I do have access to a root shell with `adb shell` and `su`

*Is there some way I could remove the screen PIN lock or change it?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection)

Comment: no your comment above is a better answer than the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your device is not encrypted with login credentials you can delete `locksettings.db`

```
adb shell su -c "rm /data/system/locksettings.db*"
```

However, bear in mind the following files are required for FBE encryption. If you delete these files you won't be able to decrypt userdata partition, all data is lost

```
/data/system/gatekeeper.password.key
/data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key
/data/system/locksettings.db
/data/system/locksettings.db-shm
/data/system/locksettings.db-wal
```

Comment: [How exactly does FBE's key derivation work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216155)

Answer (score 4):

@alexcs solution can work without root / su (sorry I can't comment on his answer) :

```
adb reboot recovery
```

(wait for reboot)

```
adb shell rm /data/system/locksettings.db
```

and reboot into normal mode with :

```
adb reboot
```

Comment: Alas this isn't working on my phone either, In recovery mode, adb won't connect anymore. Reboot and it wiill. But in recover mode "error: no devices/emulators found". Recover mode offered a menu, and delete cache seemed safest but didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

### The big axe

A brute force solution existed as I had access to fastboot too.

To remove the PIN, removed the entire userdata partition with `fastboot`

`fastboot erase userdata`

as described here:
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175887/320098

Comment: To wipe the entire partition is pretty brute force to be - it removes everything