# Stuck on ,,Phone is starting" Screen after rm /data/system/locksettings.db

Tags: adb

I got a phone with custom rom and root and usb debugging activated.
I forgot the pin so I tried this idea from @Max : [Reset PIN from adb shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224407/reset-pin-from-adb-shell)

adb reboot recovery

(wait for reboot)

adb shell rm /data/system/locksettings.db

and reboot into normal mode with :

adb reboot

I followed the commands and yes the lockscreen is now gone,
but the "Phone is starting" screen won`t go away, normally it stays for max. 5 seconds.

If the phone really needs to be factory reseted it´s okay, I just found out that I still have access to all the files via computer.

I want to ask is there any command/solution to solve this problem?

best reagards bam

Comment: try accepted answer instead

Comment: Okay, il will try it

Comment: Sadly, it did now work it says ,, /sbin/sh: su: not found" I guess i need another idea

Comment: just remove all 5 files mentioned (in recovery no `su` available)