# Factory Reset not working on moto Z3 play (beckham)

Tags: factory-reset, motorola

I have a moto z3 play (device name beckham) which I can't factory reset now. What happens is when I go to `Settings > Advanced > Reset options > Erase all data (factory reset)` but the phone simply restart back. I also tried going to fastboot mode and running the command from there and the behavior ends up the same. My third try was to just do like [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175887/172122) but when I run the `fastboot` commands it fails with the error:

> $ fastboot erase userdata 
> (bootloader) has: not found Erasing
> 'userdata'                                 FAILED (remote: 'unknown
> command') fastboot: error: Command failed
>  $ fastboot erase cache
> (bootloader) partiti: not found Erasing 'cache'
> (bootloader) Invalid partition name cacheiti FAILED (remote: '')
> fastboot: error: Command failed

Any idea on that? Thx

**Edit** All attempts were made in both USB 2.0 and 3.0
Tried in another pc (all of them linux) and also with older version (r30 and r25.0.4) of fastboot, the error gets even stranger since each time gives a different output for same input:

```
[$ platform-tools]$ sudo ./fastboot devices
0048267113 fastboot
[$ platform-tools]$ sudo ./fastboot erase userdata
erasing 'userdata'...
(bootloader) Invalid partition name userdataon-type:us
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.001s
[$ platform-tools]$ sudo ./fastboot erase userdata
(bootloader) slot-co: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffi: not found
(bootloader) partition-typ: not found
erasing 'userdata'...
(bootloader) Invalid partition name userdataon-typ
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.001s
[$ platform-tools]$ sudo ./fastboot erase userdata
(bootloader) slot-counttyp: not found
(bootloader) slot-su: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffi: not found
(bootloader) partition-typ: not found
erasing 'userdata'...
(bootloader) Invalid partition name userdataon-typ
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.001s
[$ platform-tools]$ sudo ./fastboot erase userdata
(bootloader) slot-counttyp: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-su: not found
erasing 'userdata'...
(bootloader) Invalid partition name userdataon-typ
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.001s
[$ platform-tools]$ sudo ./fastboot erase cache
(bootloader) slot-counttyp: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slo: not found
(bootloader) partition-: not found
erasing 'cache'...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

Comment: $ fastboot format:ext4 userdata;
`FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed`
it is like the device is not accepting any fastboot command, also oem unlock commands failed if this info helps..

Comment: you could try `mfastboot` not sure what's the difference, maybe it has more privileges

Comment: well, mfastboot worked at least for the erase userdata/cache commands but still not working for oem get_unlock_data.. thanks for the help

Comment: maybe first oem unlock in developer options must enabled for get_unlock_data

Comment: yep, it is enabled