# What are the adb commands for Wipe>Swipe right to Factory Reset>yes in TWRP?

Tags: adb, twrp, factory-reset

### Question

What are the `adb` commands to perform the following action sequence in TWRP:
First click `Wipe`, then `Swipe to Factory Reset`, enter `yes`?

### TWRP documentation

The interface shows the `wipe`>`Swipe to Factory Reset`>`yes` however, the [TWRP documentation](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html) does not seem to show/discuss this option.

### Note

I am aware of the `adb` commands for the set of actions that select `Wipe` the `Advanced Wipe` and selecting

```
Dalvik ART Cache
System
Cache
Data
Internal Storage
```

however they seem to be a different set of actions than the `Wipe`>`Swipe to Factory Reset`>`yes`. Similarly, the set of `Wipe`>`Format Data`>`yes` actions is also different than the `Wipe`, then `Swipe to Factory Reset`, enter `yes` sequence.

Comment: Yes based on empirical testing, it seems to me that the `adb twrp wipe data` corresponds to `Wipe>Avanced Wipe>Select Data`, and not `Wipe>Swipe right to Factory Reset>yes`. Similarly, the `adb twrp format data` command seems (to me) to be equal to the `Wipe>Format Data>yes` command, and not equal to the `Wipe>Swipe right to Factory Reset>yes`command.